# Lazy Load specific tab with React-Navigation v4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using React-Navigation V4 and the question is, Is there any way of lazy load only specific tab like if i have four tabs and i want to load two tabs after initialisation of tabs component and don't want to load other two these two only will load when user activates them.
if i use `lazy: true` in React it'll work work all tabs or either lazy load will be disabled for all or enable for all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not such a thing in react navigation v4. but if you want to achieve performance you can use other methods to kind of lazy load part of screen.

```
const TabPage = (props) => {
  const [renderHeavy, setRender] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteraction(() => setRender(true))
  }, [])

  return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
          {
              renderHeavy &&
              <HeavyComponent />
          }
          <AnotherComponent />
      </View>
  )
 }
```